# Fourier-Mellin transform in mathematica

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-mathematica, fft, geometry

I'm just getting into  image processing, but I'm relatively noobish so far ;). My aim is to detect circles with different radii with noise in mathematica. After a little bit of reading about the subject matter I found out, that the Fourier-Mellin transform seems to be an adequate method (because invariant to rotation and scaling). But I really don't know how to translate the formulas I found in papers into a code. Can anybody help me out with a code in mathematica how to perform a Fourier-Melling transform (I know I have to start with a Fourier transform..but which one of the many functions provided in mathematica do I use :/)? I wanted to start with a simple circle (pic 1) with noise and then try a picture with multiple circles (pic 2) and compare the output of the transform, but right now I'm feeling pretty stupid so far and hoping for some expertise.

Thanks in advance

Pic of circle one: http://postimg.org/image/6uefleont/

Pic of Multiple circles:http://postimg.org/image/a5vvxjl6f/

Comment: its recommended to do some background in Fourier transforms. If you're using images; then you are most likely going to need to use a 2D FFT (DFT). This question does not really.belong here. Please don't post questions on multiple.sites; dsp.stackexchange probably will offer more advice on this.

Comment: sorry..i thought the post was removed or something went wrong with the post :(. Admin can delete this post now, didn't know dsp.stackexchange :)